# How to print the content of a tr when is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, web

I have a simple table with 3 rows (excluding the headers), when some row is clicked an event click is generated and text "click!" is printed. I need to print the row content in a single log (the two td) when the row is clicked instead of print the "click!" text. How can I do it using jquery?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="family" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>David</td>
                <td>19</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#family").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
                    console.log("click!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? (`delegate()` has been superseded -from version 1.7- by `on()`.)

Comment: 1.11.1 only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#family").delegate("tr", "click", function() {

     var cellText = "";
     $(this).children().each(function() {
       cellText = cellText + $(this).html() + " ";    
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks but the output of this solution includes the <td></td> tags. I want to know the way to extract the text only, for example, if clicked on first row i expect "John 28" not "<td>John</td><td>28</td>".

Comment: well you'd have to get the .`text()` of each td.

Comment: exactly!! but I don't know how to do it. But i don't want to to it:     `$("#family").delegate("td", "click", function() {$(this).text()});` because only return the value of the current <td> which is clicked, and I need the value from the 2 <td> of each rows.